# I am getting error when trying to connect to neo4j causal cluster

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Here is my configuration

```
org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder builder = new Builder();
    org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration = builder.
credentials("neo4j","neo").connectionPoolSize(20).verifyConnection(true).uri("bolt+routing://10.1.2.12:7687")
            .uris(new String[]{
                    "bolt+routing://10.1.2.14:7687",
                    "bolt+routing://10.1.2.15:7687"
            }).build();
    return configuration;
```

Here what it is showing in error log i am using spring-data-neo4j 5.0.5 Release:-

```
2018-03-05 22:58:42.596  INFO 20927 --- [           main] Driver                                   
: Driver instance org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalDriver@71a9b4c7 created
2018-03-05 22:58:42.597  INFO 20927 --- [           main] LoadBalancer                             
: Routing table is stale. Ttl 1520270922589, currentTime 
1520270922596, routers AddressSet=[10.1.2.12:7687], writers 
AddressSet=[], readers AddressSet=[]
2018-03-05 22:58:43.236  INFO 20927 --- [o4jDriverIO-2-2] 
ConnectionPool                           : Closing connection pool 
towards 127.0.0.1:8000, it has no active connections and is not in the 
routing table
2018-03-05 22:58:43.237  INFO 20927 --- [o4jDriverIO-2-2] LoadBalancer                             
: Updated routing table. Ttl 1520271223234, currentTime 1520270923237, 
routers AddressSet=[localhost:7687], writers AddressSet=
[localhost:7687], readers AddressSet=[localhost:7687]
2018-03-05 22:58:43.259  INFO 20927 --- [           main] 
trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'getSessionFactory' of 
type [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory] is not eligible for getting 
processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for 
auto-proxying)
```

Am i missing anything in configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the last line in the log it is nothing you should be worried about. This might be more relevant if you actively want to do some post processing on the `sessionFactory` bean.

One reason why this message appear is that your are autowire the dependency in an eager (the normal) way, but that is not a problem at all, like

```
class MyClass {
  @Autowired
  public MyClass(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

Even if I repeat myself: This is not a problem at all for your application because the class is not under your control, does not require any post processing because it does not even know about the existence of Spring.

Comment: Yes it was not fault of application. Actually problem was with setting up neo4j cluster. There was problem in neo4j configuration  dbms_connectors_default__advertised__address must be set by default it is localhost